# python client throw error "call dropped by load balancing policy grpc" when remote server restart

Tags: python, grpc

Python Client throw "call dropped by load balancing policy grpc", if remote server restart. And connection never recovered afterwards.

The problem is hard to constant reproduce. But we confirmed that if a remote server restart, python client have chance starting send error message like this.

Other grpc client like java are working fine. I searched online, and it seems related to load balancing policy. And suggest to change from 'roundrobin' to 'pick first'. But I can not find where to add this args in python client.

Answer (score 1):

revert fly tiger resolve this issue